# What's wrong in the procedure I appplied, is it something conceptual I am missing?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Problem is : [image] My all working is shown here :  using 1 and 2 i am getting it to be 2pi√2R/g [image] .Here A is the COM and P is the bottom most point about which i calculated torque so as to prevent consideration of (friction for without slipping conditions). C  is centre of cylinder shell, my query is does my procedure is all gud or something is making not sense (conceptual mistake )?

Comment: Is **_A_** the center of mass, and $I_\rho$ the mass moment of inertia about it? Please explain your work.

Comment: Sry sir , didnt mention earlier : Ip is the moment of inertia about bottom most point , and A is the Centre of Mass of cylindrical shell.

Comment: Hi, [homework-like](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633) questions are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer conceptual questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have two angles, $\varphi$ and $\theta$. The problem has _one_ degree of freedom, the swing angle $\theta$. Express the equations of motion in terms of this angle and solve them to the form $$\ddot{\theta} = -\omega^2 \theta$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the correct answer is because you need to sum up torques about the center of mass, and consider the MMOI at the center of mass

$$ \tau_{\rm COM} = I_{\rm COM} \ddot{\theta} $$

When it comes to the equations of motion, tracking the center of mass is key because it separates the linear and angular equations, and as a result, the angular equation needs to be *about the center of mass*. Similarly the linear motion has to be *of the center of mass*, as in $F = m \, a_{\rm COM}$.

Comment: You cannot go wrong if you express things about the center of mass. There are special cases, just as in pure rolling, where the reference point has _zero_ instantaneous velocity that could be used also (since the coupled linear terms are zero due to the velocity being zero). Note that [Physics.SE] is not a do your homework for you site. Please consider the fundamentals of the situation and figure out on your own what steps you might have missed.